# Android listview space between items

Tags: android, listview

I have been trying to get the space between items in my listview, but I don't know what is going wrong. I have added android:divider="@android:color/transparent" and         android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" as suggested in many answers, but the space between items just doesn't show up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget76"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget78"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<!--     <RelativeLayout -->
<!--         android:id="@+id/widget778" -->
<!--         android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
<!--         android:visibility="gone" -->
<!--         android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_black" -->
<!--         android:layout_height="wrap_content" > -->

<!--         From -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text=""
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

<!--         From Time-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/llMid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
            >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
            android:contentDescription="."
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:layout_gravity=""
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/walking" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"            
            android:width="60sp" />        
        </LinearLayout>
<!--         To -->        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_below="@id/llMid"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"            
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

<!--         To Time -->        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_below="@id/llMid"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"           
            android:gravity="right" 
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
<!--     </RelativeLayout> -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Change divider `color` and it shows up..

Comment: Sorry, Just tried but it does not show.

Comment: use dp to dividerheight n try..

Comment: @MSGadag - same thing.

Comment: use without decimal number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you try like
android:layout_margin="10dp"
or
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

Comment: this should be comment.

Comment: @user3482497 - Thanks. layout_marginTop works if I add it both to the ListView and the RelativeLayout immediate after it. Anything else does not work.